# Update the value of table cell variable afterward

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a tableview with a custom cell.

Inside my UITableViewCell file I have the following code :

```
var myTipView:EasyTipView?

@IBAction func infoBtn_pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //print(diseases)
    if self.myTipView == nil
    {
        self.myTipView = EasyTipView(text: diseases, preferences: EasyTipView.globalPreferences)
        self.myTipView!.show(forView: sender)

    }
    else
    {
        self.myTipView!.dismiss()
        self.myTipView = nil
    }
}
```

and inside my UIViewController I have a tableview with the code :

```
var myTipView:EasyTipView?


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = myTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "diffCell") as! diffCell

 cell.myTipView = self.myTipView

}
```

the when I tried to use the value of self.myTipView I found it nil and this is obvious because it have no value until the infoBtn_pressed is activated and in this case  cell.myTipView is always nil when the table first created

how can i get self.myTipView to have the value after the button is pressed to use it inside UIViewController

Answer (score 2):

Once you set the `myTipView` value, You need to refresh the table by doing this :-

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding an observer to your myTipView parameter:

```
var myTipView : EasyTipView? {
    didSet {
        // Test that myTipView is non-nil
        if let _ = myTipView {
             // implement a function here that  updates the cells in the table view...
        }
     }
}
```

I'm assuming you can handle updating the table cells (incidentally, your implementation seems to suggest that every cell has the same EasyTipView property: is that your intention?). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i used delegates to notify the table when a button is clicked in the table cell and worked great (^^)